# Magento order mail notification issues

Tags: email, magento, notifications, e-commerce

I am currently developing a eCommerce website in magento. I am almost done with all the process. But still I am not finding a way to get order email notifications both by customers and admin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check email addresses in Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses

You need to check email template in system -> transactional emails. 
if you have set email template "forgot admin password" then you need to check variables in template.

Comment: Yes. I checked store email address. Everything i have set to same email already

Comment: you need to debug email template just set text "xyz" and check that you are getting mail because email variable some times create problem.

Comment: I changed the template just adding 'xyz'. But still i didn't get notified.

Comment: I need to clarify on small point. Does this deal with some SMTP configuration?

Comment: Yes you need to check smtp configuration and if it will not work then you need to debug code.

Comment: I have checked the smtp configuration with my technical hosting provider. They said the configuration are right.

Comment: My SMTP configuration are correct. But still i am not able to sort out the issue behind it.